# How to show only data of specifics rows

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

I am using Symfony and Twig templates.

I made a form which contains information belongs to people(name,birthdate, city etc ..).

All I want is  :

- all people who are living in City A appears to template who are managing City A
- all people who are living in City B go to template who are managing City B

This is my code :

```
/**
* @Route("/infoProspect", name="user_infoProspects", methods={"GET","POST"})
*/
public function getInfo(ProspectRepository $prospectRepository,AgencyRepository $CityRepository,AgencyRepository $CityRepository  ): Response
{
    $prospect = new Prospect();
    return $this->render('user/_infoProspect.html.twig', [
            'prospects' => $prospectRepository->findOneByCity(''),
            'agency' => $AgencyRepository->findOneByCity(''),
            'city' => $cityRepository->findOneByCity('Vern'),
        ]
    );
}
```

`AgencyRepository` contains `city_id` and `user_id`.
So information of people who choose City A go to Agency template which manage only City A according to its user id.

Example on my template:
I only need here cities named 'Renne' and not cities named Vern.

[image]

If you need more information ask me. Thanks.

Comment: Why do the propspects and agency don't have "Vern" in the repository function ? Wouldn't it solve your problem if the repositories only return the town asked ?

Answer (score 0):

For your controller to know which town to use, you can use a Parameter Converter like `@Entity`. Here is some code that should fit your situation :

```
/**
* @Route("infoprospect/{id_city}", name="info_prospect")
* @Entity("city", expr="repository.find(id_city)") // <- here the conversion from id_city to a hydrated doctrine entity
**/
public function getInfo(City $city, ProspectRepository $prospectRepository, AgencyRepository $AgencyRepository, CityRepository $CityRepository)
{
    // then find the people related to your city
    // if you dump city here, you will see the parameter converter found the one matching city_id
    $peopleOfCity = $city->getPeople();

    // and finally pass the people and other info to your template
    return $this->render('user/_infoProspect.html.twig', [
        'prospects' => $prospectRepository->findOneByCity(''),
        'agency' => $AgencyRepository->findOneByCity(''),
        'city' => $cityRepository->findOneByCity('Vern'),
        "people" => $peopleOfCity
    ]);
}
```

More about `@Entity` and parameter conversion here : https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#fetch-via-an-expression

Comment: i got an error "App\Entity\User object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation" when i add {id_city}

Comment: The variable `id_city` must have the same name in the `@Route` and the `@Entity` annotations, and the variable `city` must have the same name in the `@Entity` annotation and your controller function declaration (`$city`).

Comment: That is exactly what i did, almost a copy and paste.

Comment: Your error  is weird since `$city` is an instance of `City` and your error is about not finding a `User` instance. The `@Entity` annotation uses the repository linked to the Entity class.  You must also check that the generation of the URL provides a valid `city_id` ; more info about that here -> https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#generating-urls

Comment: Maybe that was not a good idea to create my template infoProspect inside my user's controller.

Comment: I think i understand the problem.
This is the route when i am on my user interface : http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/14
 But When i clicked on my page redirection to go on the template which show the people(named=prospects), i got this route : http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/infoProspect

Comment: my id is litteraly overide. 
The correct route has to be : http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/14/infoProspect

Comment: I solve the problem of the route : my url is correct now : http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/infoProspect/14       --> The expression "repository.find(id_city)" returned null

Comment: Is 14 the ID of the city or the user ?

Comment: I edited my post to show you what it look like on the template